# 3D PerspectiveCamera Rendering Depth libgdx OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: java, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx, perspectivecamera

I seem to be having a problem getting libgdx to render things correctly. I render 2 colored triangles using the vertices:

Triangle 1(blue): 
(-1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), (1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), (0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f)

Triangle 2(red):
(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f), (1.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f), (2.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f)

Triangle 2 should be to the right and behind triangle 1. I don't really know what's going on because triangle 2 is to the right and it's smaller than triangle 1, but it's being rendered in front of triangle 1. Any advice on how to fix this would be appreciated. I've tried searching google but can't find anything that helps.

Comment: Do you have depth testing enabled ?

Comment: Yep. I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to draw 2 triangles where the second triangle (the red one) is to the right and behind triangle 1:

```
glTranslated(0,0,-5);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3ub(0,0,255);                    //Triangle 1
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    glColor3ub(255,0,0);                    // Triangle 2
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f);
    glVertex3f(2.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
glEnd();
```

here is the draw results:

[image: draw results]

Comment: I'm using libgdx with GLES 2.0. What are you using? That image is what I'm expecting but it's not what I'm getting.

Comment: i'm using OpenGl with C++.

Comment: Can you post the whole code? I'm working in Java but seeing what flags you set and everything might help.

Comment: i can't post all the code because it's too long and stackoverflow won't let me post it.

Comment: Hmmm. That's inconvenient. Are there any particular flags you set?

Comment: i think if you enable the depth test it would work out, put the following line before drawing you triangles:
'glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);'

Comment: could you try putting your code on pastebin and linking here?